# Why is the boiling point of sugarcane juice lower than the boiling point of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry, boiling-point, colligative-properties, physical-organic-chemistry

As the boiling point is a colligative property, one would expect that the boiling point of sugarcane juice should be higher than pure water because Sugarcane juice contains water (75–85%), non-reducing sugars (10–21%), reducing sugars (0.3–3%), organic substances (0.5–1%), inorganic substances (0.2–0.6%) and nitrogenous substances (0.5–1%)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IZfJ.png). However, the boiling point of sugarcane juice is only 91-95°C [2]. Are there any chemistry theories that can explain this drop in boiling point?

[image][3]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IZfJ.png) Sreedevi, P., Jayachandran, L.E. & Rao, P.S. Browning and bioactive composition of sugarcane juice (Saccharum officinarum) as affected by high hydrostatic pressure processing. Food Measure 12, 1962–1971 (2018). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11694-018-9811-7

[2] Tiwari, G. & Prakash, Om & Kumar, Subodh. (2004). Evaluation of convective heat and mass transfer for pool boiling of sugarcane juice. Energy Conversion and Management. 45. 171–179. 10.1016/S0196-8904(03)00143-2.

[3]: Canilha, Larissa & Chandel, Anuj & Milessi, Thais & Antunes, Felipe & Freitas, Wagner & Felipe, Maria & da Silva, Silvio. (2012). Bioconversion of Sugarcane Biomass into Ethanol: An Overview about Composition, Pretreatment Methods, Detoxification of Hydrolysates, Enzymatic Saccharification, and Ethanol Fermentation. Journal of biomedicine & biotechnology. 2012. 989572. 10.1155/2012/989572.

Comment: Is there noted atmospheric pressure ? I am not sure it would be boiling, of placed in the boiling water bath. Unless there are volatile components or some decomposition occurs, e.g. decarboxylation. Could you quote broader context from [2] ?

Comment: I don't believe the values listed there in reference 2. It was a very very crude set-up and they do not mention what was their criterion of determining the boiling point. Boiling point of *filtered* sugar cane juice *must* be higher than pure water.

Comment: See this page http://www.sugartech.co.za/bpe/index.php

Comment: That page confuses me a little @M.Farooq. Why is the temperature of the sugar solution one of the parameters in determining its boiling point elevation? However, I have seen a source take the boiling point of sugarcane syrup as 105°C but that value wasn't justified. Nonetheless, it does give credence to your idea that source [2] is a little too crude. I have also found the boiling point of filtered sugarcane juice by a very crude method (the best my highschool could offer) and it was about 96.6°C but it had some lime water and SO2 gas passed through it as part of a larger experiment.

Comment: Evaporating water from syrup is industrially always done at reduced pressure. The boiling point of sugar solution at ambient pressure is definitely > 100°C.

Comment: The experiment in source [2] was done at atmospheric pressure as highlighted in the tables @karl.

Comment: I don't have access to that, but the number is obviously wrong, as in *unphysical*. Find other, better literature. Sugar production is an old industry, there must be dozens of textbooks in your university library. Don't waste time on one weird number from one paper.

Comment: @Karl I agree with you but the boiling point of sugarcane juice does seem to have weird properties. There is another paper DOI: 10.17654/HM013040445 whose results show that sugarcane solutions seem to start boiling at about 95-98°C, if you average T2, T3, and T4. Moreover, the experiments I am performing on sugarcane juices for my high school project are also consistently boiling below 100°C. However, I have to admit my methods are very crude, and I am adding lime water and SO2 gas to it.

Comment: @Karl: I agree with you. The temperatures reported are obviously wrong. But how? The thermocouples (Cu-constantan) were calibrated. I wonder if the tips were directly exposed to the sugar solution where galvanic corrosion could aid or conflict with the Seebeck effect. Sugarcane juice pH has been reported as 3 to 4.5: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Evolution-of-the-pH-of-the-sugarcane-juice_fig2_284455766.

Comment: @JamesGaidis There sure is some explanation for the numbers. What concerns be more is that the authors don't even discuss it (or so I understand). So either this effect must be basic textbook knowledge for anyone who works with sugar raffination, or these papers were written by a bunch of careless amateur engineers.  ?

Comment: @Karl: You hit it on the nose: engineers! I went back to the paper. The word boiling is used many many times, but "pool boiling" is specified, and that term has a specific meaning for heat transfer engineering: it's evaporation from the surface of  a stagnant liquid https://hedhme.com/content_map/?link_id=598&article_id=192 For non-engineers, boiling is boiling, but for engineers, boiling can just be evaporation at near the boiling point. Amazing how difficult it is to communicate across interdisciplinary divisions! Those engineers were not careless; we chemists were ignorant.

Comment: @JamesGaidis I change my verdict to "careless *pro* engineers". ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more plausible explanation is that it is not water that is boiling.  The  "organic substances" and maybe the "nitrogenous substances" in the juice could include some more volatile components that may pass selectively into the gas phase at a lower temperature than most of the solution.  Such a vapor would not be the pure organic or nitrogenous substance; it would carry off some water vapor as the vapor pressure of the water is a large fraction of an atmosphere.  The temperature at which such selective vapor begins to form is properly called the [bubble point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_point).

Of some relevance is the effect of the sugar itself on the boiling point.  In the absence of other solutes this effect is very small, cfailing to reach $5°C$ boiling point elevation until we have nearly 80% sucrose in the solution (by mass).  Sucrose has a large molar mass smd water has a high heat if vaporization, both of which factors attenuate the boiling point rise at concentrations relevant to sugar cane juice.  This lack of an effect from the main nonvolatile solute would enable small amounts of more volatile components to yield a bubble point lower than the boiling point of pure water.

[image]
From Ref. [[1](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-sugar-water-phase-diagram-for-the-sugar-water-system-with-boiling-point-line_fig2_232005217)]

**Reference**

1.
Willism Heffner and Hinanshi Jin, "Building a Low Cost, Hands-on Learning Curriculum on Glass Science and Engineering using Candy Glass", MRS Online Proceeding Library Archive (January 2009) 1233,
https://www.researchgate.net/deref/http%3A%2F%2Fdx.doi.org%2F10.1557%2FPROC-1233-PP03-06.

Comment: Oscar, have you tried sugar cane juice? It is drinkable, in fact it is a popular drink in South Asia road side stalls. Why do you assume there are significant amounts of nitrogenous substances and organic substances there? It would stink or perhaps be bitter if it had those nitrogenous substances in significant amounts.

Comment: @M.Farooq See OPs question. ;) And I would assume that means "residual protein". Nothing that would stink, or lower the Bp.

Comment: Proteins neither boil nor they are volatile.

Comment: Also note that the sugar itself is not very potent in raising the bp to begin with.  See the recejt modification to the answer.  On another comment, proteins could become amino acids.

Comment: This also explains the odd occurrence in DOI: 10.2298/TSCI150219213S where the boiling point is written twice. Once the study lists the boiling point as 107°C and once again as "boiling of water in sugarcane juice may start at 91-95C".